# Spring @MatrixVariable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java-8

recently I am trying to develop simple Web Application using Spring. Unfortunately, yesterday I faced problem that I cannot solve by myself:

## 1. Introduction

I have following method, that gathers price range from URL:

```
   @RequestMapping("/filter/price/{price}")
    public String getProductsByPrice(Model model, @MatrixVariable(pathVar = "price") Map<String, Integer> filterParams) {

        model.addAttribute("items", productService.getProductsByPriceFilter(filterParams));

        return PRODUCTS;
    }
```

The URL is **http://localhost:8080/webstore/products/filter/price/price;LOW=200;HIGH=900**

This is implementation of **getProductsByPriceFilter** method:

```
@Override
    public Set<Product> getProductsByPriceFilter(Map<String, Integer> filterParams) {

        Set<Product> productsByPrice = new HashSet<>();
        Set<String> criterias = filterParams.keySet();

        // start of the problem
        BigDecimal minimalPrice = new BigDecimal(filterParams.get("LOW"));
        BigDecimal maximalPrice = new BigDecimal(filterParams.get("HIGH"));
        //end of the problem

        if (criterias.contains(LOW) && criterias.contains(HIGH)) {
            for (Product product : listOfProducts) {
                if ((minimalPrice.compareTo(product.getUnitPrice()) == -1) && (maximalPrice.compareTo(product.getUnitPrice()) == 1)) {
                    productsByPrice.add(product);
                }
            }
        } else if (criterias.contains(LOW)) {
            for (Product product : listOfProducts) {
                if ((minimalPrice.compareTo(product.getUnitPrice()) == -1)) {
                    productsByPrice.add(product);
                }
            }
        } else if (criterias.contains(HIGH)) {
            for (Product product : listOfProducts) {
                if ((maximalPrice.compareTo(product.getUnitPrice()) == 1)) {
                    productsByPrice.add(product);
                }
            }
        }

        return productsByPrice;
    }
```

## 2. Problem

In above method, I have marked code fragment where I got following error (when trying to get values for "LOW" key and "HIGH" key):

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
    com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.InMemoryProductRepository.getProductsByPriceFilter(InMemoryProductRepository.java:129)
    com.packt.webstore.service.impl.ProductServiceImpl.getProductsByPriceFilter(ProductServiceImpl.java:46)
    com.packt.webstore.controller.ProductController.getProductsByPrice(ProductController.java:78)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

## 3. Question

Could someone tell me how can I extract desired values (values for following keys: HIGH and LOW) from URL mentioned at the very beginning, using **my approach**? I was trying streams() etc. but unfortunately every time I got the same exception.

Comment: Which spring version you are using ? Can you post complete error stack trace?

Comment: @Rohan stack trace updated, Spring version 4.0.3.RELEASE.

Comment: Do you get any values map `filterParams` ? Try printing map contents in controller.Also the error seems to be in `InMemoryProductRepository.getProductsByPriceFilter`.Please post that file too.

Comment: @Rohan please read my comments more carefully, getProductsByPriceFilter method is already present. And yes, filterParams  is not empty.

Comment: may be my comment was not clear. Regarding `2.Problem`, from error stack trace  `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
com.packt.webstore.domain.repository.impl.InMemoryProductRepository.getProductsByPriceFilter(InMemoryProductRepository.java:129)` ,   it seems that code is trying to assign LinkedList to Integer.Looking at code of `InMemoryProductRepository` would give more idea.

Comment: The map is a multi value map, hence you get a `List` of values instead of a single value. Either use a `MultiValueMap` instead of a plain `Map` or retrieve the element from the list instead of directly passing it to the `BigDecimal`.